# SharePoint 2019 - Result "HTTP error" with new SSL

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, sharepoint-search

New to SharePoint 2019 on-premise environment.

Search works perfectly fine when used in "http://sharepointserver/" but when tried over the configured HTTPS URL "https://sharepoint.example.com", the search gives the error below.

[image: http-error]

Crawl logs show that it can crawl the data successfully over the HTTPS.

Additional information:

- sharepointserver.domain1.com - Internal AD Domain - AAM: Default
- sharepoint.example.com - External Domain added to DNS - AAM: Intranet

I also checked the following:

- All services are started
- Restarted SharePoint Timer service
- Search Service is associated with the web app
- Disabled Windows Server Firewall but still same error

Comment: Have you correctly configured AAM? See reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-alternate-access-mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. Extended the storage of the disk (we had 50gb free before, now over 100gb) and it somehow started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of proxy between client and SharePoint Server?
It would be nice to check IIS logs to find exact HTTP status code for your search request.
Also, try to disable HTTP/2 if it's present in IIS bindings.